# What happens to completely burnt (due to fire) residence in fallout shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

One of dwellers residence quarters got burnt in a fire accident. 
I have attached the screenshot. 
Pls let me know if it is still available or damaged beyond repair? [image: burnt residence - fallout shelter]

Answer (score 4):

It's just a graphical effect. Wait a few seconds after the incident has ended and it will fade back to normal.

Comment: No @OrangeDog, I am not such a dumb player, it was so even after many hours post the accident, hence the question.

Comment: Oh that's weird. Must be a bug. You can still assign dwellers right?

Answer (score 0):

- Normally when a fire accident occurs...within seconds after the fire
  is extinguished, the room restores back to normal look.
- But in my case, due to lack of dwellers I let the fire burn for a longer
  duration. After the fire was extinguished, the room remained in
  'burnt' state for a long time.
- Close to 5 hours (my explorer took 5 hours to reach the vault by
  this time, hence I remember).
- Hence this question. But now everything is fine. Hope this info
  helps others, no need to panic if a room looks damaged. Wait and
  give it some time restore itself.

Answer (score 0):

This game has a few bugs that are not fully fixed. One of these glitches are the invisible dweller glitch. I have experienced it a few times and the only way to see them is to click on the rooms and see how many people are there or you could check by clicking in the top right and search for that dweller but I can tell you that it can be nearly impossible to drag him from room to room. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ive had that happen before, logging in and out fixed it.

infact it fixed all the graphical bugs ive encountered aswell as the "being unable to sell certain rooms/elevators bug"